# pyspark filtering rows error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying in PySpark to remove rows of customers having count smaller than 10, when grouped by `CustomerID`. So I first get the `CustomerID` of customers with count < 10. Then I filter it by taking those with `CustomerID` that are not in the remove list. But I am getting `Py4JJavaError error`. Can anyone shed me some light on how to do this correctly?

```
rm_user_1 = cleaned_df.groupBy('CustomerID').count().withColumnRenamed("count", "n").filter("n < 10").select('CustomerID').collect()

cleaned_df = cleaned_df.filter(~cleaned_df.CustomerID.isin(rm_user_1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm_user_1 = cleaned_df.groupBy('CustomerID').count().withColumnRenamed("count", "n").filter("n < 10").select('CustomerID').collect()
```

The variable `rm_user_1` is of `Row` type. You need to access the `CustomerID` values inside the row. A list comprehension will suffice:

```
rm_users = [x.CustomerID for x in rm_user_1]
cleaned_df = cleaned_df.filter(~cleaned_df.CustomerID.isin(rm_users))
```